# Flow<Set<CategoriesItemResponse>> does not seem to emit new transform value after reordering contents

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata

I'm using preferences DataStore for persisting a simple Set of `CategoriesItemResponse` (I know this is not a good practice, but that is beside the point). I have a `Flow<Set<CategoriesItemResponse>>` in my `UserPreferencesRepository` that is exposed through various ViewModels for observation.

Furthermore, I also provide methods for adding, removing & reordering the category items in the Set so that each action is then reflected in the flow stream. The add/remove functionality seems to work fine, and the screens that observe the flow do indeed react instantly to the change in data. The flow of the reorder logic seems to be flawed though.

Here's my repository:

```
class UserPreferencesRepository(private val context: Context) {
    val userFavoriteCategories = context.dataStore.data.map { prefs ->
        val categoriesJson = prefs[PreferenceKeys.userFavoriteCategories]
        println("categories flow read JSON in favorites flow = $categoriesJson")
        categoriesJson?.convertToSetObject<CategoriesResponseItem>() ?: emptySet()
    }

    suspend fun addCategoryToUserFavorites(category: CategoriesResponseItem) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
                    val categoriesJson = preferences[PreferenceKeys.userFavoriteCategories]
                    val categories: Set<CategoriesResponseItem> =
                        categoriesJson?.convertToSetObject() ?: emptySet()

                    val updatedCategories =
                        categories.toMutableSet().apply { add(category) }.toSet()

                    val updatedJSON = Gson().toJson(updatedCategories)
                    println("Updated JSON in add category: $updatedJSON")
                    preferences[PreferenceKeys.userFavoriteCategories] = updatedJSON
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Log.e(
                    UserPreferencesRepository::class.java.simpleName,
                    "Failed to add category $category to user preferences!"
                )
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun removeCategoryFromUserFavorites(category: CategoriesResponseItem) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
                    val categoriesJson = preferences[PreferenceKeys.userFavoriteCategories]
                    val categories: Set<CategoriesResponseItem> =
                        categoriesJson?.convertToSetObject() ?: emptySet()

                    val updatedCategories =
                        categories.toMutableSet().apply { remove(category) }.toSet()

                    val updatedJSON = Gson().toJson(updatedCategories)
                    println("updated JSON in remove category: $updatedJSON")
                    preferences[PreferenceKeys.userFavoriteCategories] = updatedJSON
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Log.e(
                    UserPreferencesRepository::class.java.simpleName,
                    "Failed to remove category $category to user preferences!"
                )
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun reOrderCategories(from: Int, to: Int) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
                    val categoriesJson = preferences[PreferenceKeys.userFavoriteCategories]
                    val categories: Set<CategoriesResponseItem> =
                        categoriesJson?.convertToSetObject() ?: emptySet()

                    val updatedCategories =
                        categories.toMutableList().apply {
                            add(to, removeAt(from))
                        }.toSet()

                    val updatedJSON = Gson().toJson(updatedCategories)
                    println("updated JSON in reOrder categories: $updatedJSON")
                    preferences[PreferenceKeys.userFavoriteCategories] = updatedJSON
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Log.e(
                    UserPreferencesRepository::class.java.simpleName,
                    "Failed to persist reordering from $from to $to for user categories"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The viewmodel that calls these functions and also exposes the flow is this:

```
class CategoriesViewModel(private val userPreferencesRepository: UserPreferencesRepository) :
    ViewModel() {
    //todo:sp consider getting these dynamically
    private val hardcodedCategories = listOf(
        CategoriesResponseItem(
            id = -1,
            name = "FRUITS AND VEGETABLES",
            registrationType = CategoryType.PREMIUM.ordinal,
            isSuggested = false
        ),
        CategoriesResponseItem(
            id = -2,
            name = "NUTS, NUT PRODUCTS AND SEEDS",
            registrationType = CategoryType.PREMIUM.ordinal,
            isSuggested = false
        ),
        CategoriesResponseItem(
            id = -3,
            name = "FRUITS AND VEGETABLES",
            registrationType = CategoryType.PREMIUM.ordinal,
            isSuggested = false
        ),
        CategoriesResponseItem(
            id = -4,
            name = "FRUITS AND VEGETABLES",
            registrationType = CategoryType.PREMIUM.ordinal,
            isSuggested = false
        )
    )

    private var backingCategories = emptyList<CategoriesResponseItem>()

    val userSavedCategories = userPreferencesRepository.userFavoriteCategories.transform {
        val mutableCategories = it.toMutableSet()
        mutableCategories.addAll(hardcodedCategories)
        backingCategories = mutableCategories.toList()
        println("transform called")
        emit(mutableCategories.toSet())
    }

    fun removeCategory(category: CategoriesResponseItem) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            userPreferencesRepository.removeCategoryFromUserFavorites(category)
        }
    }

    fun onItemReorder(from: ItemPosition, to: ItemPosition) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            println("reorder in VM called")
            userPreferencesRepository.reOrderCategories(from.index, to.index)
        }
    }

    fun isCategoryDraggable(draggedOver: ItemPosition, dragging: ItemPosition): Boolean {
        return backingCategories
            .getOrNull(draggedOver.index)?.registrationType == CategoryType.FREE.ordinal
    }
}
```

My issue seems to be that the UI doesn't seem to react to the reordering, despite the repository's reorder method being called and the preferences being updated.

The `transform()` is used to combine the user's data with some “premium” category samples that are only needed for the frontend. Logcat seems to indicate that the flow works up until the `println("transform called")` inside the transform lambda, but the UI does not see the change in the order of the items unless I revisit the page.

Here's the UI code:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun EditCategoriesScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    categoriesViewModel: CategoriesViewModel
) {
    val userCategories by categoriesViewModel.userSavedCategories.collectAsState(initial = emptySet())
    val reorderState = rememberReorderableLazyListState(
        onMove = { from, to ->
            categoriesViewModel.onItemReorder(from, to)
        },
        canDragOver = categoriesViewModel::isCategoryDraggable
    )

    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Column(
            Modifier.weight(1f)
        ) {
            SearchFieldAsButton(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 25.dp)) {
                navController.navigate(Screens.ADD_CATEGORIES.navRoute)
            }

            LazyColumn(
                state = reorderState.listState,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
                    .reorderable(reorderState)
                    .animateContentSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(15.dp),
                userScrollEnabled = true,
            ) {
                println("categories in UI = ${userCategories.toList()}")
                itemsIndexed(
                    userCategories.toList(),
                    key = { _, item -> item.hashCode() }) { index, category ->

                    if (CategoryType.values()[category.registrationType] == CategoryType.FREE) {
                        ReorderableItem(
                            reorderableState = reorderState,
                            key = category.hashCode()
                        ) {
                            SwipeableUnlockedCategoryItem(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .animateItemPlacement()
                                    .padding(horizontal = 12.dp)
                                    .detectReorderAfterLongPress(reorderState),
                                displayNumber = 0,
                                percentageNumber = 0,
                                categoryName = category.name,
                                onDelete = {
                                    categoriesViewModel.removeCategory(category)
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    } else {
                        val isComingSoonItem =
                            index in (userCategories.size - 2 until userCategories.size)

                        LockedCategoryItem(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .animateItemPlacement()
                                .padding(horizontal = 12.dp),
                            displayNumber = 0,
                            percentageNumber = 0,
                            categoryName = category.name,
                            isComingSoon = isComingSoonItem
                        )
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .background(
                    brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                        endY = 90f,
                        colors = listOf(
                            colorResource(id = R.color.white).copy(alpha = 0.2f),
                            colorResource(id = R.color.white)
                        )
                    )
                ),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Spacer(Modifier.height(24.dp))
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 42.dp, end = 46.dp),
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.sample_text),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall
            )

            Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))

            FoodakaiButton(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
                text = stringResource(R.string.more_insights_text),
                fontSize = 18.sp
            ) {
                navController.navigate(Screens.MORE_INSIGHTS.navRoute)
            }

            Spacer(Modifier.height(8.dp))

            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 14.dp, bottom = 4.dp)
                    .clickable {
                        navController.navigate(Screens.ADD_CATEGORIES.navRoute)
                    },
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.plus_icon),
                alignment = Alignment.Center,
                contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.add_category_icon_content_desc)
            )

            Text(
                text = stringResource(R.string.add_a_category_text),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))
        }
    }
}
```

Upon visiting the edit page for the first time we get the following logs:

> categories in UI = []
>
> categories flow read JSON in favorites flow =
> [{"id":12,"isSuggested":true,"name":"Confectionery","registrationType":0},{"id":13,"isSuggested":true,"name":"Meat
> And Meat Products (Other Than Poultry)","registrationType":0}]
>
> categories in UI = [actual-combined-list]

Now upon dragging the items and reordering them, we can see that the preferences are updated but the UI does not reflect the reordering unless we revisit the page. Here are the logs after dragging items around:

> reorder in VM called
>
> updated JSON in reOrder categories:
> [{"id":13,"isSuggested":true,"name":"Meat And Meat Products (Other
> Than
> Poultry)","registrationType":0},{"id":12,"isSuggested":true,"name":"Confectionery","registrationType":0}]
> <--- now "Meat..." is first
>
> categories flow read JSON in favorites flow =
> [{"id":13,"isSuggested":true,"name":"Meat And Meat Products (Other
> Than
> Poultry)","registrationType":0},{"id":12,"isSuggested":true,"name":"Confectionery","registrationType":0}]
>
> transform called

There is no "categories in UI" log entry here. Where am I messing it up?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your issue comes from `collectAsState` as it will only trigger recomposition on new distinct values which is checked using equality.

Even though `Set`s are iterable and some implementations do remain ordered in the way you've created them with, that order is not actually a part of `Set` contract.

"Reordered" sets are equal and so new state is not emitted.

If item arrangement is important `userSavedCategories` must produce something indexed: a `List`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I actually tried two approaches: 1)  Storing the data as a List and simply exposing it, and 2) Keeping the data represented as a Set in the preferences but exposing them as a List. Both of those seem to have failed in emitting the changes within the flow's transform lambda.